# How to identify IP address of requesting client?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How does a server actually identify the requesting client address (IP), and send a response? 
Is it possible to get the IP address of requesting client in GAE?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_remote_addr

Comment: You need to specify what language you're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a Java servlet you could use `request.getRemoteAddr()`:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    String ipAddress = req.getRemoteAddr(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Appengine with [Go](http://golang.org), the [Request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) object contains the address in the string field RemoteAddr:

```go
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, r.RemoteAddr)
}
```